# How to get keys by value in dictionary (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this dictionary that describes students courses:
the keys are names (string) and the values are lists of courses (string)

```
students_dict={"name1":["math","computer science", "statistics"],"name2":["algebra","statistics","physics"],"name3":["statistics","math","programming"]}
```

I want to create a function that gets this dictionery and  returns a new one:
the keys will be the courses (string)
and the values will be lists of the students names who take this course (list of srtings)

```
course_students={"statistics":["name1","name2","name3"],"algebra":["name2"],"programming":["name3"],"computer science":["name1"],"physics":["name2"],"math":["name1","name3"]}
```

the order doen't matter.

edit: this is kind of what im trying to do

```
   def swap_student_courses(students_dict):
students_in_each_cours={}
cours_list=[...]
cours_names=[]
for cours in cours_list:
    if students_dict.has_key(cours)==True:
        cours_names.append(...)
students_in_each_cours.append(cours_names)
return students_in_each_cours
```

Comment: You are not asking for help, you're asking us to write something for you. Please do the minimum and try to solve it by yourself.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Since you are new to Stack Overflow, may I suggest that you visit [help] and [ask]? Since you are new to Python, may I suggest that you visit, read, and follow the entire [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/)? Working through the tutorial will allow you to answer your own question.

Comment: Show us where you got stuck and why (i.e. what you expected to happen, vs. what actually happened).  Then Stack Overflow can help you.

Comment: I don't see any real correlation between your title and your question.

Comment: edited the question...
my first problem is to create the cours_list because the courses are inside lists and arn't unique... but im open to different stage suggestions for solving this... BTW sorry for bad english.. not my native language

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `defaultdict` here for simplicity's sake, but know that you can accomplish the same with a regular dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

students_dict={"name1":["math","computer science", "statistics"],
               "name2":["algebra","statistics","physics"],
               "name3":["statistics","math","programming"]}

course_students = defaultdict(list)

for name, course_list in students_dict.items():
    for course in course_list:
        course_students[course].append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a set comprehension (to first get a unique set of course names) followed by a dict comprehension (to associate course names with a list of students for whom that course appears in their respective list):

```
all_courses = {course for student_course_list in students_dict.values() for course in student_course_list}
course_students = {course:[student_name for student_name,student_course_list in students_dict.items() if course in student_course_list] for course in all_courses}
```

Your attempted approach neglected to *search through* each student's course list: you used `students_dict.has_key(cours)` forgetting that student names, not courses, are the keys of `students_dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple function you could use.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def create_new_dict(old_dict):
     new_dict = defaultdict(list)
     for student, courses in old_dict.items():
         for course in courses:
             new_dict[course].append(student)
     return new_dict
```

The only difference between python standard dict and defaultdict is that if you try to access non existing key in standard dict it will result in `KeyError` while in defaultdict it will set default value for that key to anything passed on the creation of that dict. In our case its empty list.

Implementation without defaultdict

```
def create_new_dict(old_dict):
     new_dict = dict()
     for student, courses in old_dict.items():
         for course in courses:
             try:
                 new_dict[course].append(student)
             except KeyError:
                 new_dict[course] = [student]
     return new_dict
```

EDIT----

The KeyError is raising in standard dict because if it is the first time we try to access some key, `'math'` for example, it is not in the dictionary. [Here](http://www.python-course.eu/dictionaries.php) is excellent explanation of dictionaries.

It is not a problem that values repeat because in that case we simply append new student to the list.

Comment: can u explain me why ther is a key error?
and doesnt it a problem that the val-s r repeatative?